# Multiple Graphite Instances writing to one Whisper DB

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon, whisper

I am creating a Graphite solution to collect Test data at run time.

I wanted to know can i have multiple independent graphite instances writing to the one whisper DB ?

Is this supported by carbon ?
How can i do it ?

Thanks All.

Comment: Just to add the data and metric will be viewed through one standalone UI (Grafana)